# Importing dependencies works in Pycahrm not Terminal?

Tags: python, import, terminal, pycharm

I used below solution for importing dependencies.
I found this solution works if I run the code in Pycharm but not in Terminal.
The error message in Terminal is "cannot find graphics.primitive".
I'm using Mac and Python 3.5.
Why I see different behaviors from the Terminal and Pycharm?
How may I make the solution work for both?

---

http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch10.html#_solution_169

Making a Hierarchical Package of Modules
Problem

You want to organize your code into a package consisting of a hierarchical collection of modules.

Solution

Making a package structure is simple. Just organize your code as you wish on the file-system and make sure that every directory defines an **init**.py file. For example:

```
graphics/
    __init__.py
    primitive/
         __init__.py
         line.py
         fill.py
         text.py
    formats/
         __init__.py
         png.py
         jpg.py
```

Once you have done this, you should be able to perform various import statements, such as the following:

```
import graphics.primitive.line
from graphics.primitive import line
import graphics.formats.jpg as jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the graphics package is in the Python search path.  PyCharm does this by extending `sys.path` as follows:

```
import sys    
sys.path.extend(['/Users/hackworth/Development/graphics_parent_dir', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev'])
```

You can do the same in your code replacing `/Users/hackworth/graphics_parent_dir` with the appropriate path, or you can include the full path to graphics_parent_dir in the PYTHONPATH environment variable. See the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) for details.

Another option would be to place the `graphics` package into a location the is searched by default on your system.